# My own module error: fs.readFileSync

Tags: node.js

I created my own module for node.js but i got this error, what is wrong there?

```
var React = require('react');
var fs = require('fs');
var package = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./package.json', 'utf8'));

console.log('CFG');
console.log(package);
```

Error: TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function

I use wabpack to bundle it. Thanks for help

Comment: I see no reason for that not working. What do you get when you do `console.log(fs.readFileSync);`? Anyway for that purpose you should use `var package = require('package.json');`

Comment: And `console.log(fs.readFileSync);`?

Comment: require('package.json') not work with webpack without json loader. For module I prefere non depend way to load package.json.